# What is the'debug out " from Qt's QObject::dumpObjectInfo()

Tags: qt, qt4

The doc says it "Dumps information about signal connections, etc. for this object to the debug output."

How does one set the binding of Qt's "debug output" to a file or stderr or something?

Answer (score 2):

The "debug output" refers to `qDebug`.

This goes to stderr on Linux and on Windows console apps, and on Windows GUI apps it goes through some complicated Windows subsystem I don't understand, but can be viewed with the DebugView program.

In all cases you can override the behavior by using [qInstallMsgHandler](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler).